# Receiving a class implementation of a interface as a method argument

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Is it possible to create a method who receives a Class implementation of an interface, but using the interface as argument and avoiding to receive the interface class.

I want to create an instance (and control it) of the interface implementation via reflection, so I need a valid class, not an interface class

for example:

```
interface MyInterface {}

class MyClass implements MyInteface{}


void myMethod(Class<? extends MyInterface> clazz){
    Constructor<MyInteface> constructor = (Constructor<MyInteface>) clazz.getConstructor();          
    MyInteface handler = constructor.newInstance();
}
```

This way works, but it also accept `MyInterface.class` as an argument, and I can't instantiate an interface.

```
myMethod(MyClass.class); // it's ok, what I want
myMethod(MyInterface.class); // this won't work - I want to avoid this case of use
```

Comment: There's no way to enforce usage of an implementation class via the type system. The best you can do is probably something like `if (clazz.isInterface()) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("No, dummy!") }` (or check if a no-argument constructor exists or whatever you need).

Comment: Refactor and as for a `Supplier<? extends MyInterface>`.

Comment: I agree with @JohannesKuhn. That way you can provide constructors really easily: `myMethod(MyClass::new)`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer , thanks for the tip, I believe this should be my solution anyway.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn and Rob it's new for me. Is the constructor called just when I use supplier.get()? Because I'll start some threads each with a new instance of this class. I'll take a look and try it too, thanks

Comment: If you pass `MyClass::new`, every call to `supplier.get()` will create a new instance. If you pass `() -> someInstance`, it will always return `someInstance` and not creating a new one. `MyClass::new` is mostly equivalent to `() -> new MyClass()`.